# Matlab matrix ones elements checking

Tags: matlab, matrix, element

Suppose I have a vector like `x = [1 1 1 1 1 1]`.

Now I have to write an if condition, where I have to check whether `x` contains all its elements as ones or not. How can this be done?

I searched in matlab's help, but couldn't find any direct "command"  to check such a condition. Also the size of my vector varies, so can't use something like `x(1,1) == 1 && x(2,1)` ..... condition.

Comment: Sounds like an SO question to me (sorry)

Comment: @user4341 Can't you just use `any`? E.g. `any(ones(4,1)-1)` return 0 while `any([1 2 1 1]-1)` will return 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`all(x == 1)` will return `1` if all the members are `1`.

If you'd rather check the reverse, use `any(x ~= 1)`.

Comment: @mtrw: And if i wanted to check all zeroes, is it all(x ==0)?

Comment: Small Note: This *does not work for matrices*. For matrices you need to use something like all(x(:) == 1).

Comment: @Oli: That is generally not preferred as it is two calls to `all`.